# Python with Keras Dataset Error, "X is not defined"

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to load a dataset called cifar100 from Keras, and edit it with the function `X = X[y.flatten() == 8]`, but I keep getting the Error "X is not defined".

```
from keras.datasets import cifar100

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')

X = X[y.flatten() == 8]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I would recommend you to checkout [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can help you better. Give us your full code, are you defining `X` before using it? What is the exact error?

Comment: What do you expect `X` to be on the right-hand side of `X = X[y.flatten() == 8]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X is not defined by you.
You are using `X` instead of `x_train` and `y` instead of `y_train`
may be you want to use :

```
x_train[y_train.flatten() == 8]
```